# In the Cournot Duopoly Model,why is the Equilibrium achieved at 1/3 Rd of the Market Share?

Tags: microeconomics

I've been reading it for a while,while I do get the action reaction movements,I can't understand as to how the 1/3rd value was reached. Can anyone intuitively or mathematically explain as to how it's necessarily 1/3rd and not say 1/6 or 3/5?

Comment: There should be steps in your reading explaining how it got to 1/3. If you could let us know which steps you don't get, that would help us help you better.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always necessarily 1/3rd. That just happens to be the outcome in the standard textbook example.